# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, git, macos, jenkins

I am creating build using Jenkins.
What I did form my side :

1. I set up Jenkins on MAC system (mac os el capitan)
2. configure android sdk
3. link the project form Git-hub of which I want to create build

I am getting **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0** error while build the project .I already refer few SO solution to fix this error and also update the to JDK8 but no luck!

What I want to know is ,should I also set the path of jdk here ,

> **Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Global Tool Configuration->JDK** ?

or any one have any other solution to fix this issue? 
any reference link or help will be appreciable ,
Thanks .
This is the error message 
>

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/UserModual/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fix that issue using following way .
There are list of useful terminal commands listed below.

**1. To check Java Jdk installed on MAC or not !**

> javac -version

**2. To know the path where Java being installed.**

> echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)

Then set the JDK path in Jenkins

> Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Global Tool Configuration->JDK

and restart the system .

Answer (score 8):

With the latest Android Studio version you need to switch to the embedded JDK like in the image below.

[image: resolve major.minor version 52.0 error]

Comment: 3 hours I've been trying to fix this and after trying 7 other sollutions your's helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio? I think you should set the "Build Tools Version" to the right version (probably 25.0.0).
You could change it in "File -> Project Structure -> App -> Build Tools Version" or manually under Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle (Module:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    [cut]
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: yes  sir . I am using AS for creating android app and let me clear this thing , in which way your suggestion will help in my case to fix that issue?

Comment: By your error message I see that your build tools is Gradle and it fails evaluating project ':app', the error is UnsupportedClassVersionError (running AppPlugin) you could also check your Gradle version under build.gradle (Project:yourproject) and check the line: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in the comments to @AlessandroMaglioccola's answer. Open up your project `build.gradle` and check the version of Gradle. In my case, I had this version:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

This version caused the same exception about unsupported major. minor version. The correct version is `2.2.2`.

Answer (score -3):

Right, You just check **Use Embedded JDK** in **File -> Project Structure** to remove **ERROR**, it's so simple...