# Unsupported major.minor version while running pocketsphinx-android-demo

Tags: android, android-studio, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I am trying to run [Pocketsphinx demo program](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/) in android

The tutorial tells us to load the project from Github directly

> In order to obtain the demo in the IDE, please select to checkout a
>   project from VCS, select GitHub and enter the project URL:
>   https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo.

I tried to do that but found out that `git.exe` was missing, and apparently I need to install some other software to be able to load this project directly from Github

I tried downloading the github project directly in a zip file from [here](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo)

I extracted the zip file and found the Androidstudio project files in it, but when I tried to load this project I found that it would not load because it did not have the gradle.properties file

I copied `gradle.proprties` from another one of my working Androidstudio projects into this folder. This is the content of my `gradle.properties` file:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

However, now when I load the project I am getting this error:

> Error:(1, 0) Cause: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0

If I double click on build.gradle (Project: pocket-sphinx-demo-master) in the IDE this is what I get:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':aars')
    compile project(':models')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

How do I get rid of this error? Is the pocketsphinx demo program preset to only work with a version of Androidstudio different from what I have? If so, how do I find out which one, and is it possible to set it to work with my current version? I don't think this is a problem with my Androidstudio installation as all my other android programs are working fine

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

ant.importBuild 'assets.xml'
preBuild.dependsOn(list, checksum)
clean.dependsOn(clean_assets)

Comment: Check this by adding at app gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927360/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-com-android-build-gradle-appplugin-uns)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library with easier usage ([RapidSphinx](https://github.com/icaksama/RapidSphinx)). Just add this library to your app `build.gradle` without dealing with Pocketsphinx assets and configuration.